# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `team_id`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I find this issue when I try to save the a team, how can I solve it? I am trying to deal with these associations for so long, if you guys do other issues, just let me know, please (this association has been a nightmare).

Here are the models

```
class Field < ApplicationRecord
end


class Game < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :field
 belongs_to :organiser
 has_one :team
 has_many :players, through: :team
end


class Organiser < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :games
end

class Player < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :teams
 has_many :games, through: :teams
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :players
 belongs_to :game
end
```

Here are the migrations

```
class CreateOrganisers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
  create_table :organisers do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.string :email
   t.integer :age

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end

class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
  create_table :players do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.integer :age
   t.string :address

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end


class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
  create_table :players do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.integer :age
   t.string :address

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end

class CreateFields < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
  create_table :fields do |t|
   t.string :location
   t.string :transports

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end

class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
  create_table :games do |t|
   t.references :field, foreign_key: true
   t.references :organiser, foreign_key: true
   t.integer :size

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end

class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
  create_table :teams do |t|
   t.references :player, foreign_key: true
   t.references :game, foreign_key: true

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end

class AddTeamToGames < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
  add_column :games, :team, :reference
 end
end
```

The idea is to make sure that each game will have a team of certain people. I want to access the people through game.team.player

Answer (score 0):

Your migrations doesn't have any kind of references to connect these tables.

For  example `Game` `has_one :team` is not going to create this references for you, to call `game.team` needs a column called `game_id` in `teams` table.

To add the reference you can create a migration for it:

`rails g migration AddGameToTeams game:references`

This will create that migration file may look like this:

```rb
class AddGameToTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :teams, :game, index: true
  end
end
```

Depending in the version you running rails this migration file may differ a little with adding an extra line regarding `foreign_key`.

Run the generated migration with `rails db:migrate` and it should work.

You need to apply the same concept to the rest of your tables.

Hope this helps.